# Responding Quran's Tahaddi

Tags: quran, verses

I get respond Quran's Tahaddi against↓

`وَإِن كُنتُمْ فِي رَيْبٍ مِّمَّا نَزَّلْنَا عَلَىٰ عَبْدِنَا فَأْتُوا بِسُورَةٍ مِّن مِّثْلِهِ وَادْعُوا شُهَدَاءَكُم مِّن دُونِ اللَّهِ إِن كُنتُمْ صَادِقِينَ(23) (سورة بقرة)`

My verse is: (↓

الأنسان

### إنا اعطیناک الجسم(1) لهُ العینین و الأندام(2) فسِيرُوا في العالم ثُمَّ انْظُر كيف كان عاقبة الانسان(3)

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Explicitly. A contradiction with above Quran's verse brought.

Comment: This is weak Arabic style which sounds like human made by a Arabic beginner this is no match for the qur'an. So it is no contradiction in fact anything you would write or construct would be the same. But this is off-topic and not a question.

Comment: I invite you correct that. Please help me by correcting above.

Comment: Quran advise `فی‌العرض` and I developed `فی‌العالم` and I claim we can `فَأْتُوا بِسُورَةٍ مِّن مِّثْلِهِ` as invite you help me about in above try.

Comment: I invite every people who read this question, help me correcting and growing that verse↑. Almost who expert and strong in Arabic. Regards.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is off-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am an Arabian (i.e. native Arabic speaker), and I laughed when I read the verse you made.

First of all, it is not as eloquent as Quran, not even near.

Secondly, what did you do is that you took the phrases of the Quran and changed few word; And even with these small changes, it's not even near to the eloquence of Quran. For example, you said `"إنا اعطیناک`", and you plagiarized this from Surah Al-Kawthar.
You said `"لهُ العینین"`, and you tried to mimic the verse`"‏أَلَمْ نَجْعَل لَّهُ عَيْنَيْنِ"` [surah Al-Balad - 8].
You said `"فسِيرُوا في العالم ثُمَّ انْظُر كيف كان عاقبة الانسان"`, and you literally copied 90% of the verse `"قُلْ سِيرُواْ فِى ٱلْأَرْضِ فَٱنظُرُواْ كَيْفَ كَانَ عَٰقِبَةُ ٱلْمُجْرِمِينَ"` [Surah Al-Naml - 69].

Lastly, you said `" لهُ العینین و الأندام"`, What's "اندام" ? This is not even an Arabic word! You are pathetic!

Do you know what is the sad thing? Your self-confidence.

> Allah said in the Quran [the verse you queted]: { وَإِنْ كُنْتُمْ فِي رَيْبٍ مِمَّا نَزَّلْنَا عَلَى عَبْدِنَا فَأْتُوا بِسُورَةٍ مِّن مِثْلِهِ وَادْعُوا شُهَدَاءَكُمْ مِنْ دُونِ اللَّهِ إِنْ كُنْتُمْ صَادِقِينَ * **فَإِنْ لَمْ تَفْعَلُوا *وَلَنْ تَفْعَلُوا* فَاتَّقُوا النَّارَ الَّتِي وَقُودُهَا النَّاسُ وَالْحِجَارَةُ *أُعِدَّتْ لِلْكَافِرِينَ*** }